# Is f(x) = O(g(x)) here or vice versa?

Tags: big-o

In a tutorial on the Big-O notation it is said that if `T(n) = 4n2-2n+2`, then `T(n)=O(n2)`. However, we know that `f(x) = O(g(x))` if there exists N and C such that `|f(x)| <= C|g(x)|` for all `x>N`.

But the thing is that `n2 < 4n2-2n+2` for any `n`. Shouldn't we say that `n2 = O(4n2-2n+2)` in this case?

Comment: No mathjax here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Too bad. When was it abandoned. I remember times when there was LaTeX support..

Comment: It never was supported here. It is supported on e.g. [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the below statements are true:

```
n2       ∈ O(n2)
n2       ∈ O(4n2-2n+2)
4n2-2n+2 ∈ O(4n2-2n+2)
4n2-2n+2 ∈ O(n2)
```

However talking about `O(4n2-2n+2)` does not make much sense as it's the exact same set as `O(n2)`<sup>*</sup>, so since the latter is simpler, there's no reason to refer to it as the former.

<sup>*</sup> For every function `f` such that `∃N,C: ∀x>N: |f(x)| ≤ C|4n2-2n+2|`, it is also true that `∃N,C: ∀x>N: |f(x)| ≤ C|n2|` and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

The thing about big-O notation and questions like this is to consider which term of the equation *dominates* as n (or x or other suitable variable name) gets really big. That is, which term contributes most to the overall shape of the equation graph. What term should you plot against the equation result to get the closest approximation of a straight line (approximately one-to-one correspondence).

With regards to the rest of your question, it doesn’t say that C>1. I presume C>0. As n grows, 2n + 2 becomes tiny in comparison with the squared term.

With regards as to why it’s relevant to coding: how long will your code take to run? Can you make it run faster? Which equation/code is more efficient? How big do your variables need to be (i.e. int or long choices in C). I presume if there is a "big-o" tag, there’s been at least one question on this before.